# difference between EF and Entity-SQL when working with .net core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-sql

I am beginner to .net core. And I am working on an **`enterprise application`** where there are **`multiple classes`** **`interfaces`** for multiple project inside a one solution. i know **Entity Framework** won't be a good idea if we are facing huge number of wrappers. But indeed its giving me efficiency of coding. On the other side of it **Entity SQL** has its own benefits.

But still want to really understand the best practice and which one to implement when it comes to Enterprise application knowing it will have number of classes, **`Data filtration`**, **`Generic Types`**, **`Flexibility`**, **`performance vise`** when querying DB.

Looking forward to get some really helpful understanding from **experts**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is designed for question/answer style help, not for prolonged discussions of the pros and cons of various approaches.  As such, this is off topic.

Comment: i am not asking discussion i am asking solutions. best practices and what are the experiences

Comment: Yes, and "best practices" is opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

> The "best practices" depends on the use case. Its a set of tools, not a silver bullet.

---

Sometimes EF works for your case, sometimes not. Sometimes you want a monolith, sometimes you dont.

Try, experiment fail and succeed.

Best practices regarding to techniques are irrelevant; implementation change all the time. So;

- define functional requirements
- define none functional requirements
- do a PoC with some relevant loads etc.

At enterprise level consider these additional properties:

- security
- operational functionality
- cloud / none-cloud

This is the best I can do, given your question.

Explain the case and we could give some direction; but its not a template fitted for all cases.